# Scope of editing changes in MS WORD 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

Some setting is causing Word to make an editing change to apply to all words. For example, I underline one word, but Word underlines all words.

Comment: v2010 is from 12 years ago, is there a chance you'll upgrade to a newer version? Maybe it won't occur there.

Comment: This behavior started a few months ago. I made some inadvertent change and can't imagine what did it.

Comment: So even if I upgraded, copying a document to the new release would carry the setting(s) along for the ride.

Comment: Office doesn't support upgrades. Unless you uninstall 2010, it will mean you have two different versions to open your file with.

Comment: This is the comment section, there's no answer submitted. And Windows 7 can certainly have Word > 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This means you have your style, probably the *normal style*, set to automatically update.

This is explained in depth in Word MVP Suzanne Barnhill's page [Whole Document Reformatted](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/WholeDocumentReformatted.htm).

If you press Undo immediately after, the change to the rest of the document will be undone. Better, though, is to modify the style.

Comment: That was the problem! Thanks, Charles!!

Comment: Glad I was able to help.